# Why does mdworker keep spamming the logs on Lion?

Tags: spotlight, logs

After upgrading to Lion I keep noticing strange spamming of mdworker on the logs, even though there doesn't seem to be any noticeable CPU or IO work being done. The machine is snappy but I just can't figure out why these logs keep periodically appearing:

```
29/08/12 10:17:13,861 com.apple.mdworker.lsb.0: <key>PanAndZoom</key>
29/08/12 10:17:13,861 com.apple.mdworker.lsb.0: <key>Style</key>
29/08/12 10:17:13,861 com.apple.mdworker.lsb.0: <key>ShuffleSlides</key>
29/08/12 10:17:13,861 com.apple.mdworker.lsb.0: <key>Parent</key>
29/08/12 10:17:13,861 com.apple.mdworker.lsb.0: <key>GUID</key>
29/08/12 10:17:13,861 com.apple.mdworker.lsb.0: <key>PanAndZoom</key>
29/08/12 10:17:13,861 com.apple.mdworker.lsb.0: <key>Style</key>
29/08/12 10:17:13,861 com.apple.mdworker.lsb.0: <key>ShuffleSlides</key>
29/08/12 10:17:13,861 com.apple.mdworker.lsb.0: <key>Parent</key>
29/08/12 10:17:13,861 com.apple.mdworker.lsb.0: *** process 55341 exceeded 500 log message per second limit  -  remaining messages this second discarded ***
```

Any ideas about what do they mean? Even googling for the keys doesn't seem to show anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The messages are coming from Spotlight search.

The message themselves are in relation to iPhoto's data on your images.  The tags can be found in the AlbumData.xml written out by iPhoto for sharing use (such as Spotlight and other media sharing tools)

Without more information about the version of iPhoto in use, or whether you have any issues with iPhoto itself (and Spotlight's integration) there's not more more I can tell you.